# Error Connecting to Undo Manager of Source File XYZ

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've been getting an error recently while debugging an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2008:

'Error connecting to undo manager of source file XYZ'

Any idea how I can get rid of the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wouldn't you know it; just after I post this I find a workaround in [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ErrorConnectingToUndoManagerOfSourceFileQuotwhateverDesignerquot.aspx), in the comments:

> 1) Right-click the designer file and select delete
>
> 2) Right-click the aspx file and select Convert to Web Application

Thanks to Matthew, whomever you are.

Answer (score 17):

Even simpler:

> My experiment consisted of simply opening the designer.cs file, typing a character somewhere in the file, deleting the new character, saving the file and recompiling.

Found on [That One Developer Blog](http://development.thatoneplace.net/2009/03/error-connecting-to-undo-manager-of.html) and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: For anyone arriving here looking for the same error with later versions of VS and with WPF, I found the same issue, which was only fixed after following this process, but NOT saving the file.

Answer (score 4):

I have face the same problem. And I solved it by exclude this file from project and rebuild solution. Then include this file again...DONE!

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error now. I had to just open the designer file while editing the aspx file and once done, save both. You don't even have to type any text in the designer. That did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

this one has worked for me:--
"Open desiner.cs file Type some text in it Delete the text you have typed. Save and build the application"

Thanks a lot Jitendra Kumar!!

Answer (score 1):

Open desiner.cs file
Type some text in it
Delete the text you have typed.
Save and build the application.

Answer (score 1):

*** I know this is an old question, and already answered but i'am adding my answer , hopefully it would help someone

In my case the referred file was .cs class, and since there is no .desiner.cs file, i needed another solution

so the solution for my case was to navigate tho the solution folder in windows explorer and delete the .suo file , reopen the solution and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Closing the solution and deleting the Temporary ASP.Net files directory fixed this for me. [[link]](http://forums.asp.net/t/1100585.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i double clicked an asp.net button by mistake and removed it afterwords in the aspx file and .cs file but not in the Designer.cs file. Make sure all the three got files got updated.